# Blogger não consegue ler data:post.body e data:post.url

Tags: html, css, blogger

Tenho botões de compartilhamento em redes sociais no meu blog que funcionam normalmente através do parâmetro expr:href="data:post.url/data:post.title" que pega, respectivamente, o endereço e o título da publicação em questão. Todavia, estou modificando este sistema de compartilhamento, criando uma barra lateral, inicialmente oculta (similar à charms bar do Windows 8) que terá os botões sociais. Já no fim da publicação, tenho um botão visível que quando clicado chama a barra lateral e expõe os botões de compartilhamento.

O problema é que esses botões não conseguem capturar a URL e o título da postagem através do data:post.url e do data:post.title. Eu não modifiquei nada no cerne deles, e eu já testei esses mesmos botões sem ocultá-los e verifiquei que eles funcionam normalmente, o que me fez concluir que eles só não capturam a URL e o título quando ocultos. Se eles já iniciassem visíveis, a captura é feita normalmente. Como proceder nesse caso? (detalhe: ocultei a barra em questão definindo opacity:0 no CSS e a torno visível através de um botão que muda a opacidade para 1 e a deixa ativa na tela. Não utilizei o display:none).

Desde já agradeço a todos pela atenção.
Deus abençoe! =]

[image: O front-end está praticamente pronto. Só preciso fazer com que os links funcionem!]

Comment: esse comportamento é super sinistro e por razão alguma devia estar a acontecer. Tens a certeza de que eles estão dentro do `loop` de publicações?

Comment: @Chun Sim, é bem estranho! Quanto a estar dentro do loop de publicações, significa estar em que lugar do template, necessariamente? Até então, não tinha ouvido falar desse contexto. Você pode me dar mais detalhes, por gentileza, cara?

Comment: Se esse código está dentro de um `<b:loop values='data:posts' var='post'>` ou dentro do blog widget `<b:widget id='Blog1' type='Blog'>` Ele necessita de estar dentro do `loop` de postagens para fazer *fetch* corretamente dos dados `expr:href="data:post.url/data:post.title"`. Senão ele vai determinar este link como vazio, undefined.

Comment: Ótimo, cara! Não sabia desse detalhe. Vou verificar e volto aqui para marcar tua resposta, porque, de fato, acredito ser esse o problema. ;)

Comment: Foi exatamente isso, Chum. Tua resposta ainda me ajudou a entender outro problema que não mostra determinado marcador, mas esse ainda preciso resolver. Obrigado, meu caro! Deus te abençoe! =] Resultado: http://einconformado.blogspot.com.br/2017/03/misantropia-e-penumbra.html